# Delete data in date range in Sqlite where data has been recorded as string

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I have recorded data in Sqlite where the date value is in string as so YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss sss (04/28/2020 14:02:46 9930). I am using Room Persistence in Kotlin to retrieve the dates but I cannot get it to work. This is my query at my DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM consolidated WHERE exitTrxnDTime BETWEEN DATE(:dateStart) AND DATE(:dateEnd)")
```

This is the value that I am sending

```
dateStart = '04/24/2020 00:00:00 0000'
dateEnd = '04/30/2020 00:00:00 0000'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the same format for your date strings in the query as you're using in the database.

Comment: I tried that too.. Still a no go.

Comment: `'04/24/2020 00:00:00 0000'` is not a valid sqlite time string. Observation: This format `YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss sss ` doesn't match this output `04/28/2020 14:02:46 9930`.  Regardless, there is not `/`  in (valid) sqlite dates. Here is the [sqlite date and time doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I just made a work around for it.